# Row navigation using previous and next button excel form vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel form for employee data entry work. The excel sheet contains details of employees.
I want the form to navigate through each record through previous and next button, also displaying the content in the form.

I already written the code for this but it is not working properly. It sometimes gives invalid record details while reaching begin and end of the records. Help me

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
frmEmpDetails.ComboGender.AddItem "Male", 0
frmEmpDetails.ComboGender.AddItem "Female", 1
counter = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
temp_counter = counter
lblTmpCount.Caption = temp_counter
End Sub

Private Sub btnNext_Click()
status = 1
lblTmpCount.Caption = temp_counter
If (temp_counter >= counter) Then
    MsgBox "Reached end"
Else
    temp_counter = temp_counter + 1
    txtID.Text = Cells(temp_counter, 1).Value
    txtName.Text = Cells(temp_counter, 2).Value
    txtDOB.Text = Cells(temp_counter, 3).Value
    ComboGender.Value = Cells(temp_counter, 4).Value
    txtAboutEmp.Text = Cells(temp_counter, 5).Value
    lblTmpCount.Caption = temp_counter
End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnPrev_Click()
status = 1
lblTmpCount.Caption = temp_counter
If (temp_counter < 2) Then
    MsgBox "Reached beginning"
Else
    txtID.Text = Cells(temp_counter, 1).Value
    txtName.Text = Cells(temp_counter, 2).Value
    txtDOB.Text = Cells(temp_counter, 3).Value
    ComboGender.Value = Cells(temp_counter, 4).Value
    txtAboutEmp.Text = Cells(temp_counter, 5).Value
temp_counter = temp_counter - 1
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable respective button once control reached to the end / beginning of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use subroutines to Get and Put data, and then use your navigation buttons to change the row.  Test your GetData and PutData routines to make sure they do what is expected of them.

Here is an example from a project of mine using similar controls with your textboxes and cell references.  In my example, I started the data on Row 4..  Most of the variables are declared upon activation of the form.

```
Private Sub cmdFirst_Click()   
    R = 4
    Call GetData         
End Sub

Private Sub cmdPrev_Click()
    If R = 4 Then
        MsgBox ("Already on First Record")
    Else
        R = R - 1
        Call GetData        
    End If            
End Sub

Private Sub cmdNext_Click()
    lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row   
    If R = lastRow Then
        MsgBox ("Already on the last record.")
    Else
        R = R + 1
        Call GetData        
    End If   
End Sub

Private Sub cmdLast_Click()
    R = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    Call GetData
End Sub

Private Sub cmdNew_Click()
    R = (Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row) + 1
    Call SetID
    Call ClearData
    txtID = newID
End Sub

Private Function SetID()  
Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a4", Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

    newID = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng) + 1

End Function

Private Sub GetData()
    txtID.Text = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(R, 1).Value
    txtName.Text = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(R, 2).Value
    txtDOB.Text = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(R, 3).Value
    ComboGender.Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(R, 4).Value
    txtAboutEmp.Text = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(R, 5).Value
End Sub

Private Sub ClearData()
    txtName.Text = ""
    txtDOB.Text = ""
    ComboGender.Value = ""
    txtAboutEmp.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub PutData()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(R, 1).Value = txtID.Text
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(R, 2).Value = txtName.Text
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(R, 3).Value = txtDOB.Text 
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(R, 4).Value = ComboGender.Value
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(R, 5).Value = txtAboutEmp.Text
End Sub
```