# Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error code works every other time I run

Tags: excel, vba

One of the many post on this topic, most likely answers my question, but I am too new at this to recognize it. The following code takes input from a user form and post to next row in a table. It works every other time the btsubmit button is used.   The line of code which causes the run time error is wirelistrow.Range(1, 13).Value = "123".

```
Private Sub btnsubmit_Click()
   Dim ssheet As Worksheet
   Dim wirelist As ListObject
   Dim wirelistrow As ListRow

   Set ssheet = Sheets("Database")
   Set wirelist = ssheet.ListObjects(1)
   Set wirelistrow = wirelist.ListRows.Add

   ssheet.Unprotect Password:="wire$"

   wirelistrow.Range(1, 13).Value = "123"
   findrowintable = ssheet.Range("M65536").End(xlUp).Row
   wirelistrow.Range(1, 12).Value = findrowintable

    Nextrowdata = findrowintable
    ssheet.Range("A" & Nextrowdata) = Me.tbdate

 end sub
```

Table is A3 to M6300  and I am attempting to add next row of data from an input form.
I works slick on first pass and generates error on second pass.  I click end on error message and again runs fine for next record.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd like to ask you to back up and possibly just revise the question to explain where you want the values to be saved.  ie , TextBox1 to Column C, etc.   Assuming all go to the same row.  Or explain what you are trying to accomplish.  Sometimes there might be a better way, if it was clear what you are going for in the big picture, not just solving this problem with the current approach.  If that makes any sense.. .

Comment: How many fields are on the UserForm?  What are their names and which column will hold each one's value?  From what it looks like, you are trying to put some data in 'Sheets("Database").Cells([newRow], 13)', and possibly the date in column A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this code, and see if you can adapt it to your situation.

**What happens:**

- The UserForm Activates, and the sheetName is set, and the sub ClearData gets called.
- When you click on the Update button, the sub PutData is called.
- PutData just puts the data from the UserForm controls (text boxes, list boxes, combo boxes, check boxes, etc) into a sheet, based off an address.
- ClearData resets the UserForm to be clear with a fresh date in the date TextBox.
- If you want to build a navigator to move throughout the records, that is another story, but if you did, a GetData sub would do the exact opposite of the PutData.  I will include an example of GetData, but not add the navigation controls for the sake of brevity.

**The result is that you will transfer the values from the User Form to the NEW ROW of the worksheet upon clicking "Update", then reset with a new Date.**

[image: Screenshot]

**Subs:**  included in example

```
 - UserForm_Activate  
 - cmdUpdate_click  
 - cmdClear_Click  
 - PutData  
 - ClearData  
 - GetData   (Bonus)
```

This code is placed in the code for the UserForm, declaring the variables above the Activation makes those variables' scope the whole user form and available to every sub on it.

```
Dim lastRow As Long, lRow As Long
Dim sheetName As String

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()    
    sheetName = "Database"
    Call ClearData           
End Sub

Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click()   
    Call PutData        
End Sub

Private Sub cmdClear_Click()   
    Call ClearData       
End Sub

Private Sub PutData()    
    'Save the Text from the Control into the sheet, using .Cells(row,col)
    Sheets(sheetName).Cells(lRow, 1) = txtDate.Text
    Sheets(sheetName).Cells(lRow, 13) = txtValue.Text

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Call ClearData    
End Sub

Private Sub ClearData()  
    txtDate.Text = Now      'Reset the UserForm to blank with the date as NOW.
    txtValue.Text = ""

    'Re-Acquire the last Row and set the new row variable.
    lastRow = Sheets(sheetName).Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    lRow = lastRow + 1    
End Sub
```

**Note:**
The click event for the command buttons simply CALL the sub that does the actual work.  The reason for this is evident with the sub ClearData.  It is called both when the form activates, and again after updating, as well as clicking the cmdClear button.  So instead of writing it three times and having to update it or correct it when it changes, it's all in one place, and you call it from multiple sources.

**Bonus:**
This next sub is just extra that you might want to use if you choose to navigate through all your records.  To do so, you would have a button for Prev, Next, First, Last, New, etc, and then each one lowers or raises the lRow value appropriately and calls GetData.

[Here is a link to an answer I provided that does exactly that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27242322/row-navigation-using-previous-and-next-button-excel-form-vba/27244721#27244721), the variable names are slightly different from this, but the functionality is clear.

I'm including it because it shows **How to populate a UserForm with data FROM a worksheet.**

```
Private Sub GetData()
    'If you get a navigating control for your row source, you can use a GetData sub
    'To bring data from your sheet to the User Form.  
    'Changing lRow changes the Sheets Row Source. Call GetData to refresh the Form.

    txtDate.Text = Sheets(sheetName).Cells(lRow, 1)
    txtValue.Text = Sheets(sheetName).Cells(lRow, 13)     
End Sub
```

**Also:** Since I don't see anything in your code protecting worksheets, I'm not including un-protecting them to avoid confusing future readers.  This simply provides a working example of how to move data to and from UserForms and Worksheets.